# Obtener la versión de una clase Java en repositorio CVS

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy intentando obtener la versión de una clase Java la cual se encuentra en un **repositorio cvs**, utilizando como **IDE Eclipse**.

Esto lo necesito para colocar como un `JLabel` en mi `Frame`, y así asegurarme que todas las distribuciones utilicen la última versión. Si alguien sabe como hacerlo, o si tiene algún otro mecanismo, agradecería la ayuda.

Intenté con las propiedades y métodos de las clases, pero ninguna cumple con el requerimiento.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías plantearte añadir una constante con un número de versión. No sería complicado mostrar está en el jlabel. Añades la siguiente constante en la implementación de tu frame.

`private final static VERSION = 1.0`

y por ultimo le asignas esta constante a tu JLabel

`jlabel.setText(VERSION);`

Lo unico es que cada vez que quisieses que cambie el valor de la versión, tendrias que cambiarlo manualmente.